# Finding the sum of each level in a list with nested lists

Tags: python, loops, recursion, sum, nested-lists

I need to create a python function that takes a list of numbers (and possibly lists) and returns a list of both the nested level and the sum of that level. For example:

given a list [1,4,[3,[100]],3,2,[1,[101,1000],5],1,[7,9]] I need to count the values of all the integers at level 0 and sum them together, then count the integers at level 1 and sum them together, and so on, until I have found the sum of the deepest nested level.

The return output for the example list mentioned above should be:
[[0,11], [1,25], [2,1201]]
where the first value in each of the lists is the level, and the second value is the sum. I am supposed to use recursion or a while loop, without importing any modules.

My original idea was to create a loop that goes through the lists and finds any integers (ignoring nested lists), calculate the sum, then remove those integers from the list, turn the next highest level into integers, and repeat. However, I could not find a way to convert a list inside of a list into indivual integer values (essentially removing the 0th level and turning the 1st level into the new 0th level).
The code that I am working with now is as follows:

```
def sl(lst,p=0):
    temp = []
    lvl = 0
    while lst:
        if type(lst[0]) == int:
            temp.append(lst[0])
            lst = lst[1:]
            return [lvl,sum(temp)]
        elif type(lst[0]) == list:
            lvl += 1
            return [lvl,sl(lst[1:],p=0)]
```

Basically, I created a while loop to iterate through, find any integers, and append it to a temp list where I could then find the sum. But, I cannot find a way to make the loop access the next level to do the same, especially when the original list is going up and down in levels from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
array = [1, 4, [3, [100]], 3, 2, [1, [101, 1000], 5], 1, [7, 9]]

sum_by_level = []
while array:
    numbers = (element for element in array if not isinstance(element, list))
    sum_by_level.append(sum(numbers))

    array = [element for list_element in array if isinstance(list_element, list) for element in list_element]

print(sum_by_level)
print(list(enumerate(sum_by_level)))
```

Gives the output:

```
[11, 25, 1201]
[(0, 11), (1, 25), (2, 1201)]
```

So I sum up the non-list-elements and then take the list-elements and strip of the outer lists. I repeat this until the array is empty which means all levels where stripped off. I discarded to directly saving the level-information as it is just the index, but if you need that you can use enumerate for that (gives tuples though instead of lists).